# Build System with Recursive Dependency Aggregation

Tags: c++, dependencies, build-system, premake

I recently began setting up my own library and projects using a cross platform build system (generates make files, visual studio solutions/projects etc on demand) and I have run into a problem that has likely been solved already.

The issue that I have run into is this: When an application has a dependency that also has dependencies then the application being linked must link the dependency and also all of its sub-dependencies. This proceeds in a recursive fashion e.g.

(For arguments sake lets assume that we are dealing exclusively with static libraries.)

- TopLevelApp.exe

  - dependency_A

    - dependency_A-1
    - dependency_A-2
  - dependency_B

    - dependency_B-1
    - dependency_B-2

So in this example TopLevelApp will need to link dependency_A, dependency_A-1, dependency_A-2 etc and the same for B. I think the responsibility of remembering all of these manually in the target application is pretty sub optimal. There is also the issue of ensuring the same version of the dependency is used across all targets (assuming that some targets depend on the same things, e.g. boost).

Now linking all of the libraries is required and there is no way of getting around it. What I am looking for is a build system that manages this for you. So all you have to do is specify that you depend on something and the appropriate dependencies of that library will be pulled in automatically.

The build system I have been looking at is premake [premake4](http://industriousone.com/premake) which doesn't handle this (as far as I can determine). Does anyone know of a build system that does handle this? and if there isn't then why not?

Comment: so looks like cmake will do the job required, does anyone know about any others? Scons, automake?

Comment: you can achieve it with automake via pkg-config.

Comment: thanks Michael, I think thats about all the information I need. Looks like I will be moving my build efforts to cmake :)

Comment: Well turns out that after some investigation CMake doesn't really support this in a way that is particularly user friendly. Also the documentation is less the helpful and the FIND_PACKAGE command is geared towards system installed libraries. Just thought I would let anyone reading this question that cmake is not the panacea they are looking for...

Comment: After being disappointed by cmake I moved back to premake and I have discovered that there is a patch for it to support this specific feature! I have checked out the source code and verified that it works correctly, and well enough it is actually intuitive and easy to use :)  
   
I'm going to do what I can to help ensure this feature is in the next official version of premake (which I highly recommend).

Comment: Been a while since I asked this and as it turns out that feature in premake that I am referring to in the previous comment does NOT work as desired. Specifically it does not correctly order things to be linked... There were other problems but I forget the specifics, I would recommend this feature be avoided. As a last resort I have actually written my own build system instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way that this is handled is by having the library on which you depend tell you what it, in turn, requires and what versions it has linked against. One way of doing this is via [pkg-config](http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/). For example, if you invoke pkg-config name_of_package --cflags, it will print out the necessary flags that should include flags needed to add headers of indirect dependencies. Similarly, pkg-config name_of_package --ldflags would print the necessary linker flags that include that particular library as well as its dependencies. As for build system, my  recommendation would be to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). In CMake, dependencies are found via an invocation of FIND_PACKAGE(name_of_package), which in turn defines the variable name_of_package_FOUND as 1 if the package was found, and also -- if it was found -- defines name_of_package_LIBRARIES and name_of_package_INCLUDE_DIRS to the libraries and header paths for that package as well as to the libraries and headers of its dependencies. That said, the FIND_PACKAGE mechanism works via pluggable modules written by third parties, and so while the system is supposed to set the _LIBRARIES and _INCLUDE_DIRS variables such that dependencies of dependencies are included recursively, not all of the modules do this correctly last I checked.